# Can not create wx.filedialog in an dialog class?

Tags: python, wxpython, filedialog

I create a class like this below. But when I bind an event with the "save file" button, the wx.filelog is not going to setup. It's really weird. So I change the SuperClass to be wx.Frame, then it succeeds.Can anybody tell me why? Thanks.

```
class TestDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(
        self, parent, ID, title, size=wx.DefaultSize, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
        style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE,
        useMetal=False,):
        self.pre = wx.PreDialog()
        self.pre.SetExtraStyle(wx.DIALOG_EX_CONTEXTHELP)
        self.pre.Create(parent, ID, title, pos, size, style)
        self.PostCreate(self.pre)
        self.fileButton = wx.Button(self , -1, "save file!")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCompressToFileButton, self.fileButton)
    def OnCompressToFileButton(self, event):
        wildcard = "compress file(*.cof)|*.cof|Lempel-Zivsliding window compressfile(*.lz)|*.lz"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message="Save file as ...", defaultDir=os.getcwd(),         defaultFile="", wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.SAVE)
```

`

Comment: Are you calling `ShowModal()` at any point?

Comment: yeah!I forget it!Thanks, huh!:-D

Comment: Does calling `ShowModal()` solve your problem? I'm not sure what you mean by "not going to set up". I assumed you meant that the dialog didn't show.

Comment: Yeah!It does.Thanks for your help.Actually I worked for quite a long time to solve this problem, and at the end I found it so stupid.Ho-Ho-Ho~Thanks again.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Sometimes all you need is a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

use this cod it must work with wx.Dialog

```
def OnCompressToFileButton(self, event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file",os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.SAVE | wx.OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.filename=dlg.GetFilename()
        self.dirname=dlg.GetDirectory()
```